# CodeRush QuickPair remove

Tags: visual-studio, coderush

I like CodeRush QuickPair feature.
Does anybody know how to remove quotes or braces with a shortcut?
For example:
Can I select

```
"some string"; // with quotes
```

and remove quotes with a shortcut and will get

```
some string; // without quotes
```

or select

```
(someArgument); // with braces
```

and remove braces and will get

```
someArgument; // without braces
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, CodeRush does not contain this functionality at present.

However it sounds like the kind of thing that could be created as a plugin quite quickly.

If you update your question to include some before and after examples, I'm confident I could create such a plugin for you.

---

Update: I have created a plugin to fulfil the first requirement. That of removing Quotes from around a string.

The source is [published on github](https://github.com/RoryBecker/CR_RemoveQuotesFromString) and you can [download the VSIX here](https://github.com/RoryBecker/CR_RemoveQuotesFromString/releases/latest)

---

Could you provide a little more context in your 2nd example? It does not appear to be syntactically correct C#.

I'm interested to see what sort of code you would perform this operation on. This is also necessary in order to make the plugin available in the correct context.

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question or a comment?

Comment: An answer. It serves as is for now because it indicates the functionality is not available at present. It will be a *better* answer, once I have constructed the plugin.

Comment: Thanks Rory! It's helpful for me.

Comment: You're quite welcome Ashot. If you can clarify the second set of examples I can build another plugin so help you there aswell. :)